# How to format a structured log message but ignoring some parameters in Serilog?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-6.0, serilog

I am using the standard dotnet 6 logging structure, with serilog, and sending to elasticsearch. The problem is when I do this:

```
_logger.LogInformation("Logging the value of {foo} and {bar}", foo, bar);
```

Both *foo* and *bar* will be considered a named parameter, but in fact I only want *bar* to be a named parameter. Manually concatenating *foo* looks terrible for readability, so I'm thinking there must be a way to mark a parameter as ignored, something like:

```
_logger.LogInformation("Logging the value of {_} and {bar}", foo, bar);
```

And everytime I use "_" as the name of the parameter then it will only concatenate it internally but not send it to elastic as a separate parameter.

Comment: I don't get it. Do you want ```"Logging the value of foo and {bar}"```?

Comment: `logger.LogInformation($"Logging the value of {foo} and {{bar}}", bar);`

Comment: Ok. why ```logger.LogInformation($"Logging the value of foo and {{bar}}", bar);``` is not an option?

Comment: @NickFarsi I want "Logging the value of foo and bar", but I don't want foo to be a named parameter in elastic search.
For your second question, foo is a variable and it's value is only known at runtime.

Comment: @ThomasArdal I'll see if it works like that, but if possible I didn't want to mix interpolated values with named parameters, it can make it harder to read.

Comment: Sure. But you want both interpolation and named parameters so you need to do both. You can also create the interpolated string first and save it to a variable. And then use that string as the parameter for the `LogInformation` method. But you would have two lines per log statement.